# Provide resources for several MCC (country codes) at once

Tags: java, android, localization

I need to provide resource for whole continent. 
Is it possible to add several mcc qualifiers for one resource file?

UPDATE:

From reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

> Only one value for each qualifier type is supported. For example, if
>   you want to use the same drawable files for Spain and France, you
>   cannot have a directory named drawable-rES-rFR/. Instead you need two
>   resource directories, such as drawable-rES/ and drawable-rFR/, which
>   contain the appropriate files. However, you are not required to
>   actually duplicate the same files in both locations. Instead, you can
>   create an alias to a resource. See Creating alias resources below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can.
If you are developing in Eclipse with ADT, the plugin will help you do so.

Comment: I use IDEA :) So, Is it OK if I create res/values/regional-mcc723-mcc716-mcc724-mcc334.xml ? What if I have about 20 mcc codes? Is it better to create several files?

Comment: No, it's incorrect to set more than one MCC qualifier for one resource folder, as the SDK document tells you. BUT you can prepare multiple resource folders, one of which has its  own MCC qualifier. This would work.

Comment: if you still don't catch me, I can make a screenshot to show how the resource folders should be organized, after I get back home.

Comment: As far as I understand I must create separate resource directory for each MCC. Thanks!